# UserControl in Custom DataGridViewCell Ignoring First Keystroke

Tags: .net, datagridview

I have a custom `DataGridViewCell` with a user-control as its editing control. The cell was built in the style of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.initializeeditingcontrol.aspx

For the most part, this works great. The problem is that the regular behavior of a `DataGridViewCell` is to pass the keystroke used to enter EditMode to the control, but that's not happening for this cell.

Example:

I select the custom date cell, and type in "12/24/2008", the "1" begins EditMode, and "2/24/2008" appears in the cell.

How do I get the first keystroke to the editing control?

```
Public Class DataGridViewDateCell
    Public Overrides Function KeyEntersEditMode(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) As Boolean
        'Any key-sequences with modifiers will not enter edit mode'
        If e.Control Or e.Shift Or e.Alt Then Return False

        'Accept numbers, '/', and '-''
        If (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) OrElse _
            (Char.IsDigit(ChrW(e.KeyCode))) OrElse _
            e.KeyCode = Keys.Subtract OrElse _
            e.KeyCode = Keys.Divide OrElse _
            e.KeyCode = Keys.OemMinus OrElse _
            e.KeyCode = Keys.OemQuestion Then
            Return True
        End If

        'Any other keys should be ignored'
        Return False
    End Function

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType() As System.Type
        Get
            Return GetType(DataGridViewDateEditingControl)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

The custom control has a `TextBox` on it that *always* has focus (at least, within the usercontrol). When the user types, the keystrokes are going directly to the `TextBox`. But when the `DataGridViewCell` passes the keystroke to the control, it goes to the *user control*, **not** the `TextBox`.

I added this code to the usercontrol to fix it:

```
Private Sub ucDateTime_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
    DateText.AppendText(e.KeyChar)
    DateText_KeyPress(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Comment: I never thought of using .AppendText, which works very nicely.  I also have space setup to clear the TextBox (TextBox.Text = String.Empty). Thanks!

Comment: AppendText is also very useful if you have a large scrolling textbox displaying status messages. Setting Text automatically scrolls to the top. Calling AppendText automatically scrolls to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Trap the keystroke in the form:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If MyGrid.Focused AndAlso MyGrid.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then
        MyGrid.CurrentCell = MyGrid(4, MyGrid.CurrentRow.Index)
        MyGrid.BeginEdit(True)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```